# Heroku Python Worker ProcFile

Tags: python, heroku, worker, procfile

I have a worker that I would like to run in heroku that is in the following directory:

```
project
-------worker
-------------worker.py
procfile
```

my procfile is in the root directory no problem and it runs my flask app correctly, but I've tried a few various combinations for the worker but can't seem to get it working (both project and worker folders have `__init__.py`). I've tried the following:

```
worker: python project.worker.worker
worker: python project.worker.worker.py
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the following:

```
worker: python project/worker/worker.py
```

Comment: And with a couple of forward slashes you sir get the reward of a right answer :) Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing I tried to over complicate this, it's simply like a shell

Comment: Well, it is literally executed by bash :)